# Google Cloud Endpoints (JAVA): return html content

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

How can i return html content with Google Cloud Endpoints using JAVA?
I'd like to return an html page after a user call a REST API. It is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect browser to new page after server responded to call:

```
gapi.client.yourapp.yourmethod().execute(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp); 
    if (resp.page){
        location = 'http://yourappid.appspot.com/' + resp.page + '?userid=123';
    }

});
```

But you must take care somehow about not losing your context. For example transfer userid as done in above code.

Answer (score 1):

Endpoints aren't designed to return web pages. You can look at endpoints as a framework for defining remote procedures or a RESTful API. i.e. something you'd call from JS or a mobile platform. To serve a web page on App Engine in Java you should use an App Engine servlet similar to [this example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code#creating_the_servlet_guestbookservletjava).

Comment: Thank you i used App Engine servlet to serve HTML content.

Answer (score 1):

You can return it as a string, assuming you had cached the HTML page somewhere accessible (remember, appengine has no local file storage). Within your endpoints function, you can access datastore, memcache, cloudstorage, etc...

While I do echo the other poster in saying this is not the use-case endpoints is really meant to target, the point is, endpoints is a great way to make an API with automatic generation of client libraries for multiple platforms. *Do* use endpoints for your API, but be sure it's an API function and not just HTML file serving, for which there are better patterns.

If you are using this pattern to serve *HTML partials* for an ajax-style dynamic-replacement `div` in a web app, this is fine, although if these partials are not needing processing or can be defined at deployment time, rather than being put() and get()'d from datastore, for example, then it's best to simply link them in as static resources using the appengine-web.xml / app.yaml (depending on java or python/go/php)

I hope this has helped you think more about your use-case.